# Get custom field (acf) from array of pages - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have this function for getting pages with a certain template:

```
   $parteneri = get_pages(array(
       'post_type' => 'page',
       'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
       'meta_value' => 'template_parteneri.php',
       'meta_compare' => '!='
   ));
```

This returns an array. 
How would I be able to access some custom fields (advanced custom fields) on those pages returned?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you would have to loop through pages and use

```
get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $single );
```

for each of your custom fields. I don't know any other solution at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, I made a Query with that array. I just added:

$queryObject = new WP_Query($pages);
                ?>

```
            <?php if ( $queryObject->have_posts() )

                while (
                $queryObject->have_posts() ) :
                $queryObject->the_post();

            ?>
            <p><?php the_field('continut_pagina'); ?></p>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
```